# Giving planes thickness in real-time display

Tags: objects

I've got a bunch of planes that are perfectly lined up with the coordinate space, so I can't see them when I go to either front, side, or top view. Is it possible to give planes some thickness for the real-time display, just so I don't lose track of them when I'm editing other meshes?

I can imagine giving them all a thickness modifier that is disabled for rendering, but that seems like a big pain in the neck.

Comment: You could disable the axis lines with *3D view > Properties region (`N`)> Display > Only Render*, but this will disable a lot of other stuff too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only see your problem when you are in orthographic view and your plane overlaps with one axis line. You could go into *Properties -> Object -> Display panel* and enable *Axis* or *Wire*.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this globally, rather than having to select the option for each and every plane?

Comment: @ajwood Select planes > Enable wire > Right click > Copy to selected. Or change the viewport shading to wire.